# Proof of associativity and commutativity

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, binary-operations

Say I have a set $X$ and an operation $m$ on $X$. Consider the following example.

$(x,y) \mapsto 9xy$ on $\mathbb{Z}$

How do you show that this is associative and commutative? I have already done that with, e.g.,
$(g,f) \mapsto g \circ f$ on $\{f\in Map(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}) \text{ | f is bijective}\}$. But the constant $9$ in this example in the term confuses me. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Well, what is it that you need to show? Can you write down some equations that you need to derive?

Comment: You have to show that the operation $op(x,y)=9xy$ is *commutative* and *associative* ? If so, for comm : $op(x,y)=9xy=9yx=op(y,x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, how about associativity? You know I'm new to this stuff, and what confuses me is that you actually have to show $x(yz) = (xy)z$, but what is it in this case? Is it $(9x)y=9(xy)$?

Comment: @Javiator You seem to be hung up on notation. Write $x \odot y$ for $9xy$. Do you know what it means for the operation $(x,y) ↦ x \odot y$ to be associative? Write down the equation you need to show and carefully translate it back by carefully resubstituting $9st$ whenever you encounter $s \odot t$ for some terms $s$, $t$.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I think I have a problem with the notation and translating the term to $x(yz)=(xy)z$

Comment: @Javiator Well, so say you want to to prove the associativity of $\odot$ as defined above. So you want to prove $x \odot (y \odot z) = (x \odot y) \odot z$ for all $x, y, z ∈ ℤ$. What can you do about that?

Comment: @k.stm Yes, I know what it means for the operation $(x,y)\mapsto x⊙y$ means to be associative. I have to bring $9xy$ into the representation $x ⊙ (y⊙z)=(x⊙y)⊙z$. Is this correct: $(9⊙x)⊙y = 9⊙(x⊙y)$? This constant just irritates me. Sorry for my awkward question, really.

Comment: @Javiator No. So your problem lies with substitution. Well first write $s$ for $y \odot z$ and $t$ for $x \odot y$. Can you continue from there?

Comment: @k.stm Ok, let me try. Is it $9((x\odot y) \odot z) = 9(x \odot (y \odot z))$?

Comment: This is not what you get when you write $s$ for $y \odot z$ and $t$ for $x \odot y$ in “$x \odot (y \odot z) =(x \odot y) \odot z$”. I’ll write an answer.

Comment: Stop, I got it.

Comment: @Javiator Ah, okay. Good. I’m off now.

Comment: @k.stm Is it: $9x(9yz)$?

Comment: @Javiator Yes! That’s one side of the equation, namely $x \odot (y \odot z)$. Do the same to the other side and you are practically done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This has already, almost, been answered in the comment section above but here goes.]

An operation is just a function as you already know. So to (hopefully) simplify things, write out everything in function-notation that you are used to. In the example that you mention your function is:

$f(x,y)=9xy$.

What does it mean for this to be commutative? Well, you know what it means for the operation $\odot$ to be commutative, i.e that $x\odot y=y\odot x$. This is just written with infix notation, meaning that we place the operands on either side of the function name. Written with a, perhaps, more familiar notation it reads: $\odot(x,y)=\odot(y,x)$. So I think you, also with help from the comments above, have understood that in your example,

$9xy=9yx$,

proves commutativity.

Then what about associativity? Well, again, use the same technique. You know that if $x\odot(y\odot z)=(x\odot y)\odot z$, then it is left associative (doing it from the right of course yields right associativity). So, again, with different notation you have:

$\odot(x,\odot(y,z))=\odot(\odot(x,y),z).$

In your example you would have to prove:

$f(x,f(y,z))=f(f(x,y),z)$

which yields?

(Get back to me if you need more help, but I think the step to convert it is simple enough for you to handle (and better left to you). As was said in the comments above, it's just about getting lost in notation. And again, don't forget to also prove right associativity, which is just as simple as left in this case.)